# Is there a way to cycle between full screen windows on OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, fullscreen

I have multiple Safari windows in fullscreen mode and I'd like to cycle through them using the keyboard (pretty much like <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> works when windows are not fullscreen'd). I know I can <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>->/<-</kbd>, but that will make me pass through all my non Safari windows. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. OS X, by default, does not have a method which allows you to contextually change between spaces, staying in the current application.

From my experience, your best bet is likely to focus on tabs for your navigation, replacing (or augmenting) spaces. Safari tabs can be switched between with the keyboard using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>, which would give you functionally the ability to quickly switch between pages, while still not worrying about other applications getting in the way.

Comment: I use separate windows to organize my navigation based on the subject. For example I have a window with multiple tabs for work related stuff, one for personal stuff, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried having multiple Safari tabs open at once and was able to do the 3-finger swipe to switch between each space, which got me to the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something like that but it seems that fullscreen apps turn into new desktops.
When you open exposé(F3) with fullscreen apps running you can see the "new" desktops for each app.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a Mavericks machine to test with but older Mac OSes use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to cycle through an application's windows. This worked just now on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yes, that still works for windows not in fullscreen state; as these windows are treated as other desktops, ⌘+ ` does not work.